# custom slider images xcode

Tags: ios5, uislider

I want to make a slider that is a line that is thin at the left (minimum)end and thick at the right (maximum) end and the button which slides between to change sizes between.  I have tried setting minimum and maximum track images but this didn't seem to work.  I have been able to set the images in IB but they stay the same size.  Penultimate has something like I want when you pick the pen size.  Any suggestions.

Comment: So I got this figured out except for changing the size of the thumbImage.  I can set the thumbImage but not how to change its size as it moves from left to right and back again

Comment: Show your code! What's your implementation of `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`?